# Why does Kylo Ren wear a helmet?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

My recollection is that Darth Vader wore a helmet for life support after a devastating accident. Much like some people cannot survive without dialysis after kidney failure. But Kylo Ren seems able to survive without his helmet. We get the sense that Kylo Ren is just wearing a costume like a security blanket to pretend he is his grand father. Is there any documented reason why Kylo Ren wears a helmet?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't he?  Pretty much every soldier in the past century has worn a helmet while in combat.  Granted, Jedi and Sith usually  don't wear them, but Kylo is neither, and the other people who fight - stormtroopers, rebels, pilots on both sides, etc, do.